# How detect if user view app in facebook frame or not?

Tags: facebook, user-interface

I have disable scroll in my app, so there is only scroll from facebook - it looks cute and I like it, but if came to my app directly on site, there is also no scroll bar. I tried to detect if user load page with url http://mysite.com or http://apps.facebook.com/myapps, in both ways I get the same direct address link, so I cant detect if user view my app via facebook and I need to hide scrollbar or view it on site and I need to show scrollbar. So is there a way to detect how user view my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server side language are you using? If you are inside the facebook iframe, your page will be requested with a post variable set called `signed_request`. You can check if that has been set in your code, if it has you know you are inside the facebook iframe, if it's not then you are on your site. From here you could either conditionally change your css to allow the content to overflow properly and get scrollbars, or redirect them into the facebook app.

Comment: I use php+js, you know I`ll try to check this way, it seems that it should work.